# username/password auto filled when remember password in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, google-chrome, passwords

I am developing a web application. The problem occurred only when I want chrome remember username/password.It's not happening in Firefox.The problem is -

- in login page I provide username/password and chrome remember the password. Suppose I gave 'admin' as user name and 'xxxxxxxxx'as password.
- after login we have a user profile form. where we can change the users information. Here we have two field - 'username' and password. we can change these.
- when the user profile form appeared the two field 'username' and 'password' is automatically filled up with 'admin' and 'xxxxxxxxx' (thse are the value which I want to be remembered by chrome while logged in to application).
- If I remove the remember password option from chrome, or use Firefox then the problem is not appeared.
- I thought the id of field of 'username/pssword' in login page and in user profile page were same and that is causing the problem. But after changing the id I still have the problem. Can any one please give any suggestion how can I get rid of from this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the field name in login page and user profile form are same. In your login page you have a field 'username' and in your user profile form there is also a field by 'username'. You can try by changing these.

Comment: You never explained the problem only when it occurs and when it doesn't but not what it actually is!